# Highcharts Bar Graph's Tool Tip Point Format

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have created a bar graph using HighCharts.js. Below is my declaration:

```
var myChart = Highcharts.chart(id, {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: ''
    },       
    xAxis: {
        categories: x,
        crosshair: true
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Amount (Php)'
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
        pointFormat:'<tr>' +
                        '<td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
                        '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y}</b></td>' +
                    '</tr>',                        
        footerFormat:'</table>',
        shared: true,
        useHTML: true
    },
    plotOptions:{
        column:{
            pointPadding: 0.2,
            borderWidth: 0
        }
    },
    series: data        
});
```

See image below:

[image]

[image]

I want the Point value's format in the Tooltip to be like this:

```
Apr
Collections: 7,903,113.53
Disbursements: 218,257,774.81
```

I tried changing pointFormat attribute in my declaration to the code below:

```
 pointFormat:'<tr>' +
                        '<td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
                        '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y.formatMoney(2, ".", ",")}</b></td>' +
                    '</tr>',
```

In my java script I created a function below:

```
Number.prototype.formatMoney = function(c, d, t){
    var n = this, 
    c = isNaN(c = Math.abs(c)) ? 2 : c, 
    d = d == undefined ? "." : d, 
    t = t == undefined ? "," : t, 
    s = n < 0 ? "-" : "", 
    i = String(parseInt(n = Math.abs(Number(n) || 0).toFixed(c))), 
    j = (j = i.length) > 3 ? j % 3 : 0;
    return s + (j ? i.substr(0, j) + t : "") + i.substr(j).replace(/(\d{3})(?=\d)/g, "$1" + t) + (c ? d + Math.abs(n - i).toFixed(c).slice(2) : "");
};
```

But throws an error:

```
highcharts.js?Z:20 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '", ",")' of undefined
```

Is there an easy/other way to implement what I want? Here is my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Qerjiuthn/w64runoo/).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using pointFormat, use pointFormatter callback

    `pointFormatter: function() {
      return '<tr>' +
        '<td style="color:' + this.series.color + ';padding:0">' +
        this.series.name + ': </td>' +
        '<td style="padding:0"><b>' + this.y.formatMoney(2, '.', ',') +
        '</b></td>' +
        '</tr>';
    },`

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/w64runoo/11/

Also, polluting Number.prototype is a not a clean way to do this. You can check Highcharts' numberFormat callback and extend it with your function.
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Highcharts.numberFormat

Check also global lang options where you can define thousandStep and decimalPoint http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/lang.thousandsSep